# How can I show that the ideal $(2x, x^2+1)$ does not generate all of $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

> How can I show that the ideal $(2x, x^2+1)$ does not generate all of $\mathbb Z[x]$?

Not sure of what to try first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$(2x, x^2+1)\subset (2, x^2+1)$ and 
$$\mathbf Z[x]/(2, x^2+1)\simeq (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]\big/(x^2+1)\ne \{0\}.$$

Comment: $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]\big/(x^2+1) = (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]$ since $1$ is a root of $x^2+1$ and $1 \in \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z[x]$. Is this correct?

Comment: No. It is the same as $\mathbf Z[x]/\bigl((x+1)^2\bigr)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2)$ (via the homomorphism $x\mapsto x+1$).

Comment: But $1$ is a root of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. So, we have $(\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[x]\big/(x^2+1) = (\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z)[1]=\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. No?

Comment: Or is it because $x^2+1$ is reducible over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ that I'm wrong?

Comment: No, because the ideal  $\bigl((x+1)^2\bigr)$ is not the ideal $(x+1)$. Actually, $x+1$ is a non-zero nilpotent element.

Comment: To answer your last comment,  $x^2+1$ is irreducible over , say, $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$, abdnd the quotient would be isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z[i]$. Modulo $2$ the ideal $(x^2+1)$ is the square of the ideal $(x+1)$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

First guess an element that is not inside, for example $x$.
Then prove that is not inside by contradiction.

If $x\in(2x,x^2+1)$ then there are polynomials $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$, $q(x)=b_0+b_1x+...+b_kx^k$ such that $x=p(x)\cdot 2x+q(x)\cdot (x^2+1)$ so $$x=(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)2x+(b_0+b_1x+...+b_kx^k)(x^2+1)$$

Equating the coefficients at both sides

$1)$ $b_0=0$

$2)$ $2a_0+b_1=1$

$3)$ $2a_{r+1}+b_{r+2}+b_r=0$ for $r\geq 0$ or equivalently $b_r=-2a_{r+1}-b_{r+2}$

Using $3)$ lots of times on $2)$, as $b_r=0$ for $r$ big enough we get

$\begin{align}
1&=2a_0+b_1 \\
 &= 2a_0-2a_2-b_3 \\
 & =2a_0-2a_2+2a_4+b_5 \\ 
 &\dots \\
 &=2a_0-2a_2+2a_4+\dots \pm 2a_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
\end{align}$

And as the left hand side is $1$ and the right hand side is even we get a contradiction. This shows $(2x,x^2+1)\neq \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: As a remark, an ideal generate the entire ring iff 1 is inside. Hence you can skip the guess and use 1 from the beginning.

Comment: The coefficients are not properly equated. We should have $b_0=0$ and $2a_0+b_1=1$ and $2a_1+b_0+b_2=0$.

Comment: I don't think this method is going to work.

Comment: @AlJebr I am sorry, I answered before without checking the computations. Now it should be good.

Answer (score 2):

Both generators evaluate to $2$ at $x=1$. It follows that $f(1)$ is an even integer for all $f(x)$ in the ideal. Therefore the ideal cannot be all of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.